# gson intrepret specific field as capitalized

Tags: java, json, serialization, enums, gson

I have a class with some fields, e.g.

```
public class Message {

    public Enum Type {
        TEXT,
        PICTURE;
    }

    private Type type;
    private String text;
    private int id;
}
```

Let's say I have a json like the following

```
[ { "id" : "1",
    "data" : "hello",
    "type" : "text",
  },
  { "id" : "2",
    "data" : "<someImageUrl>",
    "type" : "picture",
  },
]
```

I can easily deserialize it by calling

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Message> messages = gson.fromJson(jsonResult, new TypeToken<List<Message>>() {}.getType());
```

Cool.  Unfortunately, the Type field remains null, because of the casing difference between the json object and the defined instances in the enum.  How can I alter gson's behaviour so that it will interpret json Type objects as capitalized.

Potential workaround I have thought of:

- assign ordinal values to the enum type that will match what's given in the json (i.e. `TEXT("text")`
- split the json result by the delimiting character "},"
- replace all occurences of -someEnumType- with -SOMEENUMTYPE-

something like

```
public enum Type {
    TEXT("text"),
    PICTURE("picture");

    private final String value

    private MessageType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value
    }
}
...

   String[] jsonResultSplit = StringUtils.split(jsonResult, "},") 
   for (String jsonMessage : jsonResultSplit) {
        for (MessageType messageType : MessageType.values()) {
            if (jsonMessage.contains("\"type:\" : \"" + messageType.getValue() + "\"")) {
                jsonMessage.replace(
                        "\"type:\" : \"" + messageType.getValue() + "\"",
                        "\"type:\" : \""
                                + StringUtils.capitalize(messageType.getValue() + "\""));
            }
        }
    }
    jsonResult = StringUtils.join(jsonResultSplit);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<Message> messages = gson.fromJson(jsonResult, new TypeToken<List<Message>>() {}.getType());
```

However this seems kind of hacky, and the string will be split incorrectly if a message contains "}," or something.

Comment: Write a custom serializer/deserializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to register your own [`TypeAdapter`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) to do the conversion

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Type.class,
            new TypeAdapter<Type>() {

                @Override
                public void write(JsonWriter out, Type value)
                        throws IOException {
                    out.value(value.name().toLowerCase());
                }

                @Override
                public Type read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                    return Type.valueOf(in.nextString().toUpperCase());
                }
            }).create();
```

---

Note that you should also annotate

```
private String text;
```

with `@SerializedName("data")` as it doesn't match the JSON name.

```
"data" : "hello",
```

Comment: Perfect, I will implement this and accept the answer as soon as I get it up and running.

Comment: Does Gson not have an equivalent to Jackson's `@JsonValue`?

Comment: @chrylis Not as far as I know. You have to write your own, which isn't particularly hard with `TypeAdapter`.

Comment: outstanding.  Was able to write another typeadapter as well based off this very clear example.  Thanks so much

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not hard, but obnoxious when there's a clear pattern that could be applied. :-/

Answer (score 7):

Simplest way is to use @SerializedName annotation for your Enum.

```
public Enum Type {
    @SerializedName("text")
    TEXT,

    @SerializedName("picture")
    PICTURE
}
```

`@SerializedName` can be used not only for capitalization but also to change name of your enums or variables, for example

```
public enum Gender {
    @SerializedName("boy")
    MALE,

    @SerializedName("girl")
    FEMALE
}
```

[Reference](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/test/java/com/google/gson/functional/EnumTest.java?r=1230)

Also as @Sotirios suggested, you need to annotate `text` to map json key with your variable.

```
 @SerializedName("data")
 private String text;
```

You can now deserialize your json using Gson as earlier

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Message> messages = gson.fromJson(jsonResult, new TypeToken<List<Message>>() {}.getType());
```

Hope this helps...