# UpperCase all json keys using java and regex to find the matches

Tags: java, json, regex

I'm beginner in java and have to replace all  `json Keys` to upper Case .

My json can contain `arrays` (maybe nested Ones) and objects

Here is an example of my json input  :

```
 {
 "transactionId": 181,
 "Shipments": [
   {
     "shipmentId": 2,
     "picklistId": "24RZ",
     "ExtOrderId": "23-127",
     "boxType": "120"
    }
   ]
  }
```

Here is an example of my json Output :

```
    {
  "TRANSACTIONID": 181,
  "SHIPMENTS": [
   {
     "SHIPMENTID": 2,
     "PICKLISTID": "24RZ",
     "EXTORDERID": "23-127",
     "BOXTYPE": "120"
    }
   ]
  }
```

I have tried to create an adapter but no chance to make it work correctly ,

- Do i Have to use a `regex` and a `replaceAll("everything before a : " , "upperCase()")`

I'm reaching out to you guys to help me on this task because i could not find a way out to find a solution

Comment: Why not use a JSON parser and change it? You must be producing or consuming this JSON, right? Don't use use Jackson or anything to do so?

Comment: Yes i have used GSON but could not do the upperCase for arrays https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75386940/uppercaseadapter-does-not-support-json-array

Comment: @VLAZ If you have a suggestion i'm taking it with pleasure

Comment: But for your question i'm just extracting the fields using an other IDE that is case sensitive and my end user is not respecting the input json case sensitivity , so i prefer to put all keys in upperCase and then extract all upperCase keys-Values so that i don't have problems after

Comment: "*If you have a suggestion i'm taking it with pleasure*" my suggestion is "don't use regex for something that's not within the purview of regex". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542141) is something that can change to upper case. [Here is some more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29469788). Or [change the naming polcy](https://shekhargulati.com/2015/09/10/gson-tip-using-a-different-fieldnamingpolicy/). [Deserialise into a Map](https://www.baeldung.com/gson-json-to-map) and you can apply transformation to keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions is to flatten the JSON, upperCase() the keys and unflatten the JSON. Library *Josson* can do the transformation.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"transactionId\": 181," +
    "    \"Shipments\": [" +
    "        {" +
    "            \"shipmentId\": 2," +
    "            \"picklistId\": \"24RZ\"," +
    "            \"ExtOrderId\": \"23-127\"," +
    "            \"boxType\": \"120\"" +
    "        }" +
    "    ]" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "flatten('.').entries().map(key.upperCase()::value).mergeObjects().unflatten('.')");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "TRANSACTIONID" : 181,
  "SHIPMENTS" : [ {
    "SHIPMENTID" : 2,
    "PICKLISTID" : "24RZ",
    "EXTORDERID" : "23-127",
    "BOXTYPE" : "120"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: what is the imports that i ave to do for this please ? thank s a lots

Comment: It's compiling but getting a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule how could correct that , are there a specific version that i have to use so that Josson  would work ?

Comment: And if you can take a look at an Adapter that you have done but missing a little piece to get Arrays https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75386940/uppercaseadapter-does-not-support-json-array , thank a lot

Comment: _Josson_ is using the latest _Jackson 2.14.2_. The exception `NoClassDefFoundError` will be gone if your project uses the correct one.

Comment: imported jackson-datatype-jsr353-2.14.2.jar  , josson-1.4.3.jar ,  jackson-core-2.14.2.jar , jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar

Comment: Now getting this error ,  The type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode cannot be resolved.

Comment: Here are the imports import com.octomix.josson.Josson;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;

Comment: import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNode;

Comment: The import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNode cannot be resolved Is there a specific version of jar that i have to install ? jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar i'm using (maybe it is deprecated ? )

Comment: Sorry, should be this one: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode

Comment: Yes , The type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files What does this mean :// sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251783/discussion-between-java-bee-and-raymond-choi).